# How to make a material-ui responsive to reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, material-ui

Tell me which tool to use based on **material** for design with **react** components?

Try http://www.material-ui.com - for reactjs, but there is no responsive grid

Try https://github.com/react-materialize/react-materialize - This lib is not reliable and difficult for stability working of the application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[material-ui](http://www.material-ui.com/#/) already uses flexbox for their layouts. The components themselves are responsive as well. It seems that they did [implement a grid layout](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/pull/5808). However, it looks like it's only available in the pre-release branch. The way I see it you have three options here:

1. Implement your own responsive grid using flexbox
2. Use a grid layout library, such as [react-grid-layout](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout)(for React) or [flexboxgrid](https://github.com/kristoferjoseph/flexboxgrid)
3. Get their pre-release channel `npm install material-ui@next`